# Bootsrap mulitple select box Limit results and scroll to load more

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstraps multiple select box, I am populating the select box with about 5000 options that the user can select. (it is very slow as I would have expected it to be). Is there a way to limit the number of options displayed to say 1000 and then if the user wants to see more options they can scroll down further within the select box and another 1000 options is loaded. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 5000 or 1000 options in a multi-select sounds like a horrible user experience. I would find a different way to do it. Possibly https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 5k options for a drop-down, then it is advisable to use Typeahead of bootstrap. It will be helpful because it will fetch options based on the characters which user has typed in. So it will not make your page to load slowly because no option data will be fetched on page load.

Check the typeahead plugin [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: thank you for your advice, is there any way of dynamically loading data into a bootstrap multiple select box

Comment: I have to check if it is available. But I do not recommend it because users won't like to scroll down too much and searching among a lots of options text, but they will be happy if you put such typeahead plugin. They can type in the option they want.